# Why thevinin is applied to voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, theory, linear

Why do we use superposition with  independent voltage source? and it isn't linear(I mean homogeneity and additivity).

EX: independent Voltage source V = 4 volts is not linear(homogeneity and additivity), but we use superposition to solve such circuits. Also we use Thevinin and voltage source is not linear

Comment: Give an example, the question is cryptic.

Comment: Hope it is clear now

Comment: No. An independent voltage source is not non-linear. Explain, for example, how it does not conform with additivity. Or even how you might even apply the additivity property to an isolated voltage source.

Comment: I mean thevinin theorem states that network elements have to be linear, but voltage source is non-linear and we apply thevinin on the network when it has a voltage source!!

Comment: But a voltage source is not non-linear.

Comment: linear means stratify homogeneity and superposition.

Comment: Yes, that statement is correct.

Comment: so voltage source isn't linear

Comment: yes it is. Prove that it's not. You can't simply quote two criteria and state that a source doesn't satisfy them, you must show this to be the case.

Comment: I don't have to write it down to know. Anyway

say battery simple model V is a Vs with R in series --> vs = R*i + c  now double that current -->R*2*i+c  that has nothing to do with the voltage. homogeneity is broken

Comment: Where does the 'c' come from? If you double I, you double V

Comment: I said battery in series with an internal resistor doubling i won't double v.

Comment: There is no 'c'. \$V=I.R\$ ; and \$ 2V=2I.R\$, or the rest of the world has got superposition wrong.

Comment: you still applying this concept to a resistor which I total convinced it is linear, but this equation doesn't have anything to do with voltage source!!

Comment: v = 4 not v =  4*i

Comment: @Chu: he is actually correct, but his English is way bad. A one-port resistive network containing a voltage source may not be linear as seen from the port! Classic textbook example: https://books.google.com/books?id=RiFO63RFRL4C&pg=PA4

Comment: @Respawned Fluff, ah! OP didn't indicate that, as far as I see. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 2):

For a linear circuit system:
Ax = c

A is a matrix of linear transformations
x is a vector of variables (currents and voltages)
c is a vector of stuff not involving the variables (which are the independent sources)

So c, the sources, do not affect the linearity of the system.

And superposition works where you can the split up the sources:
\$ Ax = c \$
if \$ c = c_1 + c_2 \$
and \$ Ax_1 = c_1 \$
and \$ Ax_2 = c_2 \$
then \$ A(x_1 + x_2) = c \$ and \$ x = x_1 + x_2 \$

Comment: But if you change x it won't affect C

Comment: Given a circuit A with sources C, you can find solution(s) x. So x is the behavior of the idealized circuit system. If you then change x arbitrarily, then x most likely will not be a solution and it would be an useless exercise.

Comment: I don't understand why linear circuit system do have non-linear elements(v source) in it!!

Comment: What defines whether a system is linear is that the operator A must be linear transformations. The sources always come in on the right side as c and simply have no bearing on whether the system is linear. In the context of linear system, a v source, for example, does not operate on the variables, so you cannot even say whether it is linear or non-linear.

Comment: To clarify your battery example above: a battery is not necessary a voltage source, that is, a voltage source as defined in circuit analysis. You can model a battery as a voltage source. But you have chosen to model the battery as a voltage source in series with a resistor. Now when you put this battery into the circuit, you have to put in two elements, the resistor and the voltage source. The resistor, which obeys ohms law, will end up in A as a linear operator. The voltage source will end up in c and have no bearing on the linearity of the system.